# MLP Classification

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm new to Machine Learning and I'm working on a python application that classifies poker hands using a dataset which I will post snippets. It does not seem to work well. And I am getting the following error:

```
File "C:Testing.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(classification_report(training_data, predictions))
  File "C:Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 1391, in classification_report
    labels = unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 84, in unique_labels
    raise ValueError("Mix type of y not allowed, got types %s" % ys_types)
ValueError: Mix type of y not allowed, got types {'multiclass-multioutput', 'multiclass'}
```

Here is the code I managed to create:

```
import pandas as pnd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix

training_data = pnd.read_csv("train.csv")
print(training_data)
training_data['id'] = range(1, len(training_data) + 1)  # For 1-base index
print(training_data)

test_data = pnd.read_csv("test.csv")
result = pnd.DataFrame(test_data['id'])
print(result)
test_data = test_data.drop(['id'], axis=1)

training_datafile = training_data
labels = training_datafile['hand']
features = training_datafile.drop(['id', 'hand'], axis=1)
scaler = StandardScaler()
# Fit only to the training data
scaler.fit(training_datafile)
X_train = scaler.transform(training_datafile)
X_test = scaler.transform(training_datafile)
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100, 100))
mlp.fit(features, labels)
predictions = mlp.predict(test_data)
len(mlp.coefs_)
len(mlp.coefs_[0])
len(mlp.intercepts_[0])
result.insert(1, 'hand', predictions)
result.to_csv("./ANNTEST.csv", index=False)
print(classification_report(training_data, predictions))
```

The following are snippets of the data sets I am using the training and testing data respectively:
Train data
[image]
Test data
[image]

The program basically works I am managing to predict the poker hands as seen below:
[image]

What I wish to do know is display some sort of accuracy percentage or some sort of a function like classification_report. Guiding me in the right direction would be of great help!

Comment: Does that work if you explicitely set the argument header set to 0 while loading you data ? 
test_data = pnd.read_csv("test.csv", header=0)

Comment: No i still get the same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting an error here because you're using the `classification_report` incorrectly. Let's take a look at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html):

```
classification_report(y_true, y_pred, ...)

y_true : 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix    
         Ground truth (correct) target values.

y_pred : 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix
         Estimated targets as returned by a classifier.
```

You pass `training_data` as the first parameter (which is not an 1d array). Instead, you need to pass the *true* hands of your test data which you want to compare to your predicted hands of your trained classifer. Accordingly, this might work:

```
print(classification_report(test_data["hand"], predictions))
```

Comment: return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4433)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13742)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'hand'

Comment: Judging the error message, `KeyError: 'hand'`, `hand` is not included in `test_data`. I don't know where the actual values of `hand` are saved in your data. In any case, you have to pass the *true* values of your test data.